# Php Mailer / GoDaddy

Tags: php, forms, email, authentication, phpmailer

I uploaded a contact form page with attachment option coded in html with embedded php (contact.php) via GoDaddy, but when I want to fill out the form and submit it, I get a lot of errors that I don't understand.

I am using php mailer and a php include to another php page (bootstrap.php) from my contact page.

Below is the code:

Contact page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <?php 
       ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       include('bootstrap.php');
   ?>
</head>
<body>
   <div class = "wrapper">   
       <section class ="bulk">
           <?php if(isset($_GET["status"]) == "thanks") { ?>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <p class = "text-center"> Thanks for the email! We will be in touch shortly </p>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <h1 class = "text-center">
                      We look forward to working with you!
                    </h1><br>                    
                    <h4 class = "text-center" style="font-weight:normal;">
                        Please complete the form and attach file
                    </h4>

               <!-- form stuff -->                                         
                    <div class ="row">                        
                        <div class="contact">                                                                                                                              
                            <form method ="post" action ="contact.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="name" id ="name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {echo $_POST['name'];} ?>">                                           
                                    <?php 
                                        if ($error) {
                                            echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "<br>";
                                        }                                           
                                    ?>
                                </div>                                                                                                                                                                         
                                <!--email-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="email" id ="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {echo $_POST['email'];} ?>">
                                    <?php 
                                        if ($error) {
                                            echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "<br>";
                                        }                                           
                                    ?>
                                </div>   
                                <!--msg-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message">Message</label>                                            
                                    <textarea name ="message" class="form-control" id ="message" placeholder="Enter message" rows = "10" ></textarea>
                                    <?php 
                                        if ($error) {
                                            echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "<br>";
                                        }                                           
                                    ?>
                                </div> 
                                <!--attachments-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="attachment" >Attach your file</label>                                            
                                    <input type ="file" name='attachment' id='attachment'>
                                </div>
                                <!--Hpam Sponypot -->
                                <div class="form-group" style="visibility: hidden">     
                                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                                    <input type ="text" name="address" id ="address">  
                                    <p> Humans, do not fill out this form! </p>
                                </div>                                     
                                <!--attachments-->
                                <div class = "buttons">
</div><button type="submit" value="Send" class="button">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><br><br>
                    </div>
                     <?php } ?>
            </section>
```

And this is the php page (bootstrap.php) that is included on the top of the contact page:

```
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new phpmailer();

// VARIABLE DECLARATIONS

$errName = '';
$errEmail = '';
$errMessage = '';
$error = false;


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name = trim($_POST["name"]); //trim destroys whitespaces like "Tab" or  "Spacebar"
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$phonenumber = trim($_POST["phonenumber"]);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);

// Attack #1 preventor - Spam Honeypot

if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
    echo "SPAM HONEYPOT";
    exit;
}

// Attack #2 preventor - Email header injection hack preventor 

foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if(stripos($value, 'Content-Type:') !== FALSE) {
        echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";
        exit;
    }
}

 // Check if name has been entered
if ($name == "") {
    $errName = 'Sorry, you have not entered a name, please try again.';             
}

// Check if message has been entered
if ($message == "") {      
    $errMessage = 'Sorry, you have not typed a message.';      
}

// Check if email is valid
if (!$mail->validateAddress($email)) {        
    $errEmail = 'Sorry, please enter a valid email address.';
}

// Flag error messages if any tests fail

if ($errName || $errMessage || $errPhonenumber || $errEmail) {
    $error = true; // Boolean to flag validating error messages in the HTML
} 
else {             


    // EMAIL BODY IFF FORM VALIDATION IS SUCCESSFULL! 
    $email_body = "";
    $email_body = $email_body. "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body. "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body. "Phone number: " . $phonenumber . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body. "Message: " . $message;


    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');


    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 465;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "#############################";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "###################";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('companyname@gmail.com', 'Company Name');

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

    //Add attachment
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']);
//        if (isset($_FILES['attachment']) &&
//            $_FILES['attachment']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
//            $mail->addAddress($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],
//                                 $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
//        }


    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML($email_body);


    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else {             
    }
    header("Location: contact.php?status=thanks");
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

These are the error messages that come up when submitting the form:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in 

/home/username/public_html/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 2395
Could not access file: Array
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.85                 
#2 Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:46:23 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this     

system          to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mywebsite.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net Hello     

n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net [46.252.205.183]250-SIZE 52428800250-    

8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mywebsite.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net Hello     

n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net [46.252.205.183]250-SIZE 52428800250-   

8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 xxx
CLIENT -> SERVER: IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 xxx
CLIENT -> SERVER: IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIw==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net closing    
connection
SMTP connect() failed.     
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.     
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output     
started at /home/myusername/public_html/contact.php:4) in     
/home/username/public_html/bootstrap.php on line 148
```

The code in line 148 of bootstrap.php is

```
header("Location: contact.php?status=thanks");
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know there is a logical error above with regards to the $errPhonenumber missing, but I removed this error before obtaining the error message shown above.

Comment: I believe this error....Notice: Array to string conversion in class.phpmailer.php on line 2395...Could not access file: Array....
Is caused by this line of code:

$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']);

Because $_FILES[‘attachment’] is an array.  You need the path to the file which is accessed by $_FILES[‘attachment’][‘tmp_name’]....

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php .....

For my settings I use port 587, not 465.  I also set $mail->SMTPSecure to ‘tls’ and not ‘ssl’.  You’ll notice in comments of your code those same values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are passing the whole `$_FILES['attachment']` array to the `addAttachment()` method in the first parameter and not a string containing the filepath. Hence the error message!

This path to the location of the file is in `$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']` as you have not moved the uploaded file from tmp storage to a permanant file location.

Parameter 2 while optional could also be passed if you wish and can be found in `$_FILES['attachment']['name']`

So amend this piece of code like this

```
//Add attachment
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
```

The prototype for the method is:

```
public function AddAttachment($path,
                              $name = '',
                              $encoding = 'base64',
                              $type = 'application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try read the error message? It includes a link to the troubleshooting guide, which covers GoDaddy and how to connect to gmail. You've based your code on some random, obsolete example rather than the maintained ones provided with PHPMailer.

In this case, you're telling it to connect to `smtp.gmail.com`, but it's showing you connecting to `n1plcpnl0057.prod.ams1.secureserver.net`, which is a GoDaddy server - they are intercepting and redirecting your SMTP traffic - so of course your gmail credentials will not work.

In addition to that, your use of `addAttachment` is both wrong and unsafe, but it's not what's causing the connection problem.

BTW, your SMTP transcript shows your ID and password in a form that's easily decoded, so you should change them.